# Correctly using multiple clusters in a kubectl config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am tyring to switch between a couple different clusters I have defined in a kubectl config file but it seems no matter what I do it defaults to the defined dev cluster. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the config file named combined:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://zlty10129.vci.att.com:6443
  name: moks-dev-cluster
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://zlp30531.vci.att.com:6443
  name: moks-prod-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: moks-dev-cluster
    namespace: com-att-moks-dev
    user: default-user
  name: dev
- context:
    cluster: moks-prod-cluster
    namespace: com-att-moks-prod
    user: default-user
  name: prod
current-context: prod
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-user
  user:
    token: m28194@moks.att.com:enc:pass
```

And when I try to switch to prod I still get the dev context:

`kubectl config --kubeconfig=combined use-context prod`

`kubectl config view`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://zlty10129.vci.att.com:6443
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: com-att-moks-dev
    user: default-user
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-user
  user:
    token: m28194@moks.att.com:enc:pass
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just renamed the `combined` file to `config` and it works.